# Es correcta la forma de implementar estas dos tablas de una tienda online?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

estoy haciendo la base de datos de una tienda, y tengo la duda de si debo tener una **tabla_cestas** y otra **tabla_historial** tal que asi :

```
CREATE TABLE cestas(
    id INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    usuario_id INT NOT NULL,
    producto_id INT NOT NULL,
    cantidad INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(usuario_id) REFERENCES usuarios(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(producto_id) REFERENCES productos(id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE historial(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    usuario_id INT NOT NULL,
    producto_id INT NOT NULL,
    cantidad INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    fecha_compra TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(usuario_id) REFERENCES usuarios(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(producto_id) REFERENCES productos(id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Yo prefiero tenerlo asi dividido, para que cuando el usuario finalice la compra se cambien de una a otra la tabla (de **cesta** a **historial**) pero tambien he pensado que podria tener solo una por ejemplo llamada **compras** y que un campo fuese **boleano** que se llamara **esComprado** y segun fuese `true` o `false` pues se sabria si esta comprado.

Yo personalmente prefiero tener en dos tablas, pero como son **muy parecidas** a lo mejor **no es buena practica**.

Un saludo.

Comment: Creo que sería mejor que al usuario le añadas un campo de tabla anidada que apunten a IDs de cestas, como idea, y la tabla historial te la cepilles

Answer (score 0):

En **WooCommerce** o en **Prestashop** el sistema que utiliza es el siguiente:

Un usuario tiene un carrito en el cual añade artículos, y cuando los compra se crea una orden, eliminando los objetos del carro y añadiéndolos al historial de pedidos.

Es decir, en la forma en la que lo has hecho está bien.